# column filter with data types displaying error:using data tables

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have used this code to generate search box for every fields. But it is showing syntax error at the line **.columnFilter({**. how to solve this problem

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//initialisation code
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
             .columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [ {
                type: "select",
                values: [ 'Gecko', 'Trident', 'KHTML', 
                          'Misc', 'Presto', 'Webkit', 'Tasman']
                 },
                 { type: "text" },
                 { type: "number" },
                 { type: "date-range" },
                 { type: "number-range" }
            ]



        } );
    } );


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like a javascript syntax problem.  Try changing to this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    })
         .columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
    aoColumns: [ {
            type: "select",
            values: [ 'Gecko', 'Trident', 'KHTML', 
                      'Misc', 'Presto', 'Webkit', 'Tasman']
             },
             { type: "text" },
             { type: "number" },
             { type: "date-range" },
             { type: "number-range" }
        ]



    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function(){
          $('#example').dataTable().columnFilter();
             }`)

make usure you have closed the dataTable() brackets before .columnFilter.

Hope it works.